# How to model my machine learning problem?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, alert, prediction

I'm working on generating alerts in motorcycle competition. In this competition, we have approximately 100 competitors. we have data about rider position, speed, timestamp ...,  In this project i need to create a machine learning algorithm that predicts the time needed for a rider to go from a specific point to another in the course based on the rider histories in the course.
 do you have any suggestion about how can i modelize my problem, or do you have some research or proposition that may help me?

Comment: It's spelled 'to model' not 'to modelize'.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how much sophisticated model you need.

For a start, assuming that

1. You have riders position A and want to estimate when he'll arrive to a position B
2. There is a rich history of this rider driving on this track

I'd simply

1. Pick a set of historical points around A and around B.
2. Figure out which points form pairs (i.e. they correspond to the same lap in the same race)
3. For each pair compute the time difference
4. return the average

Comment: thank you for your respond, it will be a good start point for the project, but, in my use case, I need to create smth that depend in competitor.maybe a combination between a machine learning algorithm (by using  the speed the distance the timestamp and predict the duration) and the competitors data.